# Why would the amount of packets received be greater than the amount of packets sent?

Tags: wifi, wireshark, packet

I am new to wifi, and as I was looking at .pcap files, I noticed that one connection took an absurdly large amount of time.  Another thing that stood out is that the amount of packets received was so mush more than the number of packets sent.  What does this mean, and does it mean any suspicious?

Comment: Interpreting arbitrary packet captures is not a topic of information security.

Comment: This has nothing to do with security, try https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Many requests are like this. For example, if you make a request to https://stackoverflow.com you'll send like 1kb of data and you might get something like 500kb back. Because TCP fragments packets into little pieces the larger the data you're receiving the more packets there will be.